# Is there a way to route a record/policy to all employees to sign

Tags: document, records-management, records-center, digital-signature

I am looking into add a record library into my company's SharePoint site. The main use for this would be to store digital copies of records/forms/policies that employees are required to sign. I want to know if it is possible to upload a single source form that can be assigned to everyone to read and sign. The goal is to route the source to each person, and the copy they sign gets added to the record library.

I want to add in the caveat that I have been (and currently am) working in the 2016 beta, which does not have access to workflows (so I haven't used them and can't test them). My back-end SharePoint admin wants to rebuild our site, so we're stuck with the beta and no workflows until a later date. I don't expect to actually be able to set up the records center and workflows yet, I just want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a **library on root site** which contains all the **Policy documents**. Than after you need to create a **webpart to show policies** to users like below.

[image]

On the acceptance of any document, You need to insert the same document name with accepted (Current Login) user & current date time to any list. Once the user clicks on it, You must have to disable the button by tracking from that list.

The **link on the document & download button** will do the same as it allows users to download the copy of the document.

If you wish to get the copy back from the user than you can add the **upload button** & do the same like **Accept button**.

**Note:-** If I miss/misunderstood something in this than kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have created\worked on this kind solution in the past many times. One thing that you want to avoid is to store the readership information in Sharepoint list. Regardless of the size of company you will start hitting Sharepoint Thresholds very quickly (say 10 policies updated yearly for company size of 500 means that after 3 years you will have 15k of records, list views will start to fail after 5k, there are of course some way to accommodate large lists in SP but those are quite flaky). All readership information which is transactional should be kept outside of SP (you could use BCS to store that as external content type). Without workflows it is will be quite roundabout way of doing it but it still cab be done. 1. Timer job creates readership task (Normal SP Task list with notifications when the task is assigned). 2. Custom web part that would show all 'My Policies' with custom action button 'Confirm Read' 3. When clicked a custom web service is triggered that A. Completes the task, records the reading confirmation in external SQL table. C. Deletes the task so you can keep task list clean.